# AttributeError: module 'rdpywheel' has no attribute 'sms'

Tags: python-3.x

I write a public python lib, when I tried to publish the lib and import it in current project, shows error:

```
AttributeError: module 'rdpywheel' has no attribute 'sms'
```

this is the lib path look like:

[image]

why current project could not recognize the sms package path? what should I do to fixed it? I am use it in code like this:

```
vfs_phone = rdpywheel.sms.cn_virt_msg.get_sms_phone_number()
```

and import like this:

```
import rdpywheel
```

I also tried to add this import in sms folder's `__init.py__`:

```
from rdpywheel.sms.cn_virt_msg import CnVirtMsg
```

Comment: it is still in the early stages, but it got today an update, so you could try that